PCIe x16 Link to GPU detected with "limited by 16.0 GT/s PCIe x4"
I'm trying to establish a stable connection to my RTX4090 by using 2 PCIE MCIO x8 connections. The board is an ASUS K14PA-U12. The Device adapter is from cpayne "MCIO PCIe gen5 Device Adapter 2* 8i to x16".
During startup dmesg shows the following for the NVIDIA card:
[    1.258785] pci 0000:c3:00.0: 63.012 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 16.0 GT/s PCIe x4 link at 0000:c0:03.1 (capable of 252.048 Gb/s with 16.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link)

Device 0000:c0:03.1 is a PCI bridge capable of x4 only:
>lspci -v -s  0000:c0:03.1
c0:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14a5 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
>lspci -vv -s  0000:c0:03.1 | grep LnkCap
 LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 32GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L1 <64us

OS is Ubuntu 22.04. Why is the system detecting the PCIe device with only 4 lanes?
Any BIOS setting necessary?
Thank you in advance

A lot of motherboards don't operate in full x16 mode when there's more than one PCI device connected.   Case in point my ROG STRIX motherboard in my gaming PC, when there's two PCI devices connected, only one can operate in x16 mode and the other drops to x8 mode.  If there's three, it drops to 1 in x16, and 2 in x4.  You should look into your motherboard's specs and its PCI operation modes.  There's no real way to override this.

It's a server system with AMD EPYC Genoa CPU which supports 128 PCIE lanes. Not comparable with a gaming CPU with 20 PCIE lanes maximum.

Removed the second MCIO 8i cable to check if PCIe x8 will be activated. Tried different cables as well. But without success. The system keeps detecting only 4 lanes for this connection. It's so frustrating!

This will be a stupid question but did you test to see if the GPU when put in one of the three x16 ports on the server board in fact works properly at x16 mode?  If not, then it's the GPU.  If yes, then it's likely the adapter you're using being incompatible or having some other issues.  (Yes, I looked up your board's manual and specs)

The GPU was in use for several month on a different server before with x16 GEN4 by using SLIMSAS connections over a redriver adapter. Now I added a second GPU to the system. Same result. Both GPUs are running at 4 lanes only. Probably some misconfiguration for pci bifurcation inside the BIOS. It's strange.

Response from ASUS support center:
MCIO interfaces on ASUS K14PA-U12 are intended to be used for NVME storage devices and preconfigured for „Bifurcation-Mode“ x4x4. There is no BIOS setting available for changing this bifurcation mode.
What I figured out together with the help of some guys from the community:
In order to change bifurcation on this particular board on MCIO ports it's necessary to use setup_var.efi inside an EFI-Shell environment.
For example changing bifurcation on G0 (Glink 0) which is used for MCIO1 and MCIO2:
setup_var.efi -n AsusCpmDxioTopology 0x7 [mode]  

modes:
0 = x16  1 = x8x8  2 = x4x4x8  3 = x8x4x4  4(default) = x4x4x4x4
setup_var.efi -n AsusCpmDxioTopology 0x89 [0x60+last lane]

0x63(default) = 4 lanes 
0x67 = 8 lanes 
0x6f = 16 lanes 
Use Uefi-Editor to figure out more details.
